# Can I change linenumber colour?

Tags: color, line-numbering

I've tried adding the `lineno` package to my document. It's nice but I would like to make the numbers a different colour, like a light grey or blue, if possible.

Can I do this in my style document where I add the package, somehow? I am already using the `xcolor` package as well.

Comment: Change the colour... where? :D Are you talking about regular paragraphs? Or some environment like a table? Your question is very vague on this (or maybe I'm missing some very obvious information).

Comment: Sorry if it's vague, what I wanted was to change the colour of the line numbers themselves. @AmbikaVanchinathan answered my question. :)

Comment: Yeah I saw that. :D No problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to change the colour of the line number to blue, then use this in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\small\color{blue}}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\small\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry still new to this site, wasn't aware I had to click that green arrow. :)