# Change fontsize on line numbers in lineno package

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

Can't see anything in the documentation about this, but wondering if anyone knows if it's possible / how it is done.

My eyes hurt!

[CTAN: Package lineno](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lineno)

Comment: Thank you! Please post this as an answer so that I can pick it.

Comment: Oh boy, I was looking in package documentation rather than user manual. I see what you mean re: it being close to a duplicate of that previous question. Still, I don't think it would hurt to have this as a google-able answer. It certainly would have saved **me** some time! I'll leave it up to you as to whether you post it as an answer. Or - if you know this land better than I, and suggest deletion, I'll follow you suggestion (again)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will be happy to delete this. In the manual in section **4.7 How the line numbers look like** you find the example

```
  \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small}
```

Obviously you may replace `\normalfont\bfseries\small` by whatever you like, and as e.g. discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247165) also change the color and so on.