# Resize line numbering

Tags: thesis, line-numbering

I use Texmaker to help with writing in LaTex. I have added line-numbering to the draft of my thesis. The size of the line number is a bit too small. Is there a way to make the size a bit bigger?
The preamble and some of the code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}     %For adding Figures
\usepackage{float}        %For removing figure borders
\usepackage{tabularx}      %For making tables
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}      % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Generates table from .csv
\usepackage{longtable}     %Allows multi-page tables
\usepackage{rotating}      %Allows for single page landscape using 
\usepackage{pdflscape}     %Allows for landscape
\usepackage{multirow}      %Allows for merging across rows
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-uncertainty-signs=\pm, 
        separate-uncertainty=true}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

Insert title page content here

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\mainmatter
\linenumbers

\chapter{Introduction}
\setstretch{1.5}
\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont

This portion contains the general body of work.\\
It contains a lot of text, numbers and citations.\\
There are plenty of pretty figures and LOTS of tables.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507924/134144 should be useful.

Comment: This worked. Thank you.